# Material UI TextField with type datetime-local date picker with seconds

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-admin

I am using react-admin and want to edit date and time including seconds using DateTimeInput. However, I am not able to do that. I tried following:

Option 1:

```
<TextField
  id={id}
  {...input}
  step='1'
  value={format(input.value) || ''}
  variant={variant}
  error={!!(touched && (error || submitError))}
  helperText={<InputHelperText touched={touched ?? false} error={error || submitError} helperText={helperText} />}
  label={<FieldTitle label={label} source={source} resource={resource} isRequired={isRequired} />}
  {...options}
  {...sanitizeInputRestProps(rest)}
/>
```

Option 2:

```
<DateTimeInput label='Scratched Time' source='scratched_time' disabled={!scratched} />
```

But, I am not able to edit the seconds field.

Comment: It's not possible with DateTimePicker of MUI, only TimePicker supports setting seconds [mui pickers docs](https://mui.com/components/time-picker/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to put "step" inside "inputProps" instead. ;-)

```
<TextField 
    inputProps={{
        "step": 1,
    }}
    type="datetime-local"
/>
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mD83r.png)